# Legend in two Figures side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats, subfig

I have the following code to plot two figures side-by-side and one legend for each figure:

```
\documentclass[a4,9pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfigure[Figura da esquerda]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \begin{axis} [
                ybar=0pt,
                enlargelimits=0.2,
                width=0.45\textwidth, 
                height=0.35\textwidth,
                minor y tick num = 1,
                ymajorgrids,
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.02,0.5)}},
                bar width = 6pt,
                legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},    
                    anchor=north,legend columns=4},     
                ylabel={Number of hours worked},
                symbolic x coords={$n=50$, $n=100$, $n=150$, $n=200$},  
                xtick=data,  
                ymax=15,
                ymin=0,
                %nodes near coords,  
                %nodes near coords align={above}
                ]  
                \addplot[fill=orange] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 8) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$,15)}; %Solucao 1
                \addplot[fill=red] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 1) ($n=100$, 7) ($n=150$,7) ($n=200$, 12)}; %Solucao 2
                \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 9) ($n=150$,9) ($n=200$, 14)}; %Solucao 3
                \addplot[fill=violet] coordinates 
                {($n=50$,4) ($n=100$, 7) ($n=150$,9) ($n=200$, 13)}; %Solucao 4
                \legend{Sol.1,Sol.2,Sol.3,Sol.4}  
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\qquad
\subfigure[Figura da direita]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \begin{axis} [
                ybar=0pt,
                enlargelimits=0.2,
                width=0.45\textwidth, 
                height=0.35\textwidth,
                minor y tick num = 1,
                ymajorgrids,
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.02,0.5)}},
                bar width = 6pt,
                legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},    
                    anchor=north,legend columns=4},     
                ylabel={Number of hours worked},
                symbolic x coords={$n=50$, $n=100$, $n=150$, $n=200$},  
                xtick=data,  
                ymax=15,
                ymin=0,
                %nodes near coords,  
                %nodes near coords align={above}
                ]  
                \addplot[fill=orange] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 3) ($n=100$, 4) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$, 11)}; %Solucao 1
                \addplot[fill=red] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 2) ($n=100$, 4) ($n=150$,4) ($n=200$, 4)}; %Solucao 2
                \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 12) ($n=150$,12) ($n=200$, 14)}; %Solucao 3
                \addplot[fill=violet] coordinates 
                {($n=50$,3) ($n=100$, 5) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$,11)}; %Solucao 4
                \legend{Sol.1,Sol.2,Sol.3,Sol.4}  
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Número máximo de frentes de colheita}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

However, I would like to draw only one legend (below) for these figure, like this:

[image]

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: unrelated but `article` doesn't have `a4`  or `9pt` options. Also the text (in the form posted to this website) is UTF-8 so `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` is wrong (you can simply delete it as utf8 is the default encoding)

Comment: If these were merely images with legends, you could arrange the layout you need without problem. Is exporting the `tikzpicture`s to images for inclusion via `\includegraphics` an option?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I would create three separate files and `\includegraphics` individually.

Answer (score 5):

See `legend to name` (page 269 in the [`pgfplots`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfigure[Figura da esquerda]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \begin{axis} [
                ybar=0pt,
                enlargelimits=0.2,
                width=0.45\textwidth, 
                height=0.35\textwidth,
                minor y tick num = 1,
                ymajorgrids,
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.02,0.5)}},
                bar width = 6pt,
                legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},    
                    anchor=north,legend columns=4},     
                ylabel={Number of hours worked},
                symbolic x coords={$n=50$, $n=100$, $n=150$, $n=200$},  
                xtick=data,  
                ymax=15,
                ymin=0,
                legend to name={mylegend},
                %nodes near coords,  
                %nodes near coords align={above}
                ]  
                \addplot[fill=orange] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 8) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$,15)}; %Solucao 1
                \addplot[fill=red] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 1) ($n=100$, 7) ($n=150$,7) ($n=200$, 12)}; %Solucao 2
                \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 9) ($n=150$,9) ($n=200$, 14)}; %Solucao 3
                \addplot[fill=violet] coordinates 
                {($n=50$,4) ($n=100$, 7) ($n=150$,9) ($n=200$, 13)}; %Solucao 4
                \legend{Sol.1,Sol.2,Sol.3,Sol.4}  
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\qquad
\subfigure[Figura da direita]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \begin{axis} [
                ybar=0pt,
                enlargelimits=0.2,
                width=0.45\textwidth, 
                height=0.35\textwidth,
                minor y tick num = 1,
                ymajorgrids,
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.02,0.5)}},
                bar width = 6pt,
                legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},    
                    anchor=north,legend columns=4},     
                ylabel={Number of hours worked},
                symbolic x coords={$n=50$, $n=100$, $n=150$, $n=200$},  
                xtick=data,  
                ymax=15,
                ymin=0,
                %nodes near coords,  
                %nodes near coords align={above}
                ]  
                \addplot[fill=orange] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 3) ($n=100$, 4) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$, 11)}; %Solucao 1
                \addplot[fill=red] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 2) ($n=100$, 4) ($n=150$,4) ($n=200$, 4)}; %Solucao 2
                \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 12) ($n=150$,12) ($n=200$, 14)}; %Solucao 3
                \addplot[fill=violet] coordinates 
                {($n=50$,3) ($n=100$, 5) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$,11)}; %Solucao 4
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\ref{mylegend}
\caption{Número máximo de frentes de colheita}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you update your post with the code that provides the accompanying image? It currently doesn't and is missing your suggested `legend to name` option.

Comment: As David Carlisle's has already pointed out in a comment, the document class options `a4` and `9pt` are unknown to the `article` document class and thus have no effect. (Sure enough, one finds `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [a4,9pt]` in the log file.) Please also replace `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and recompile in order to fix the mess with the accented characters in `Número` and `máximo`.

Comment: @werner - Sorry about that.  Wrong copy.

Answer (score -1):

The following code does what you want.

You can try latexplots.com or latexplots.netlify.app,
however this tool is designed for 2D pgfplots graphics, you can use specific blocks for your graphics.

To do it you have to:

1-Add a blank rectangle below the first image and remove the label; 2-Move the label of the second image. 3-Overlap bofh images (\hspace{-2cm}). 4-Optional, move the captions (\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=bottom,margin={-0.5cm,-3cm}}) in this case using subfloat instead of subfigure, package subfig. More details in: http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/caption/caption-eng.pdf

```
\documentclass[a4,9pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepackage{subfloat}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm,top=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=bottom,margin={-0.5cm,-3cm}}%{oneside,margin={-0.5cm,-3cm}}
\subfloat[Figura da esquerda]{
\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
     extra description/.code={
     \draw[draw=white,
                 draw opacity=1,
                 fill opacity=1]
          (0.2,-.4)rectangle(0.8,-0.2);
},
},
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \begin{axis} [
                ybar=0pt,
                enlargelimits=0.2,
                width=0.45\textwidth, 
                height=0.35\textwidth,
                minor y tick num = 1,
                ymajorgrids,
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.02,0.5)}},
                bar width = 6pt,
                legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},    
                    anchor=north,legend columns=4},     
                ylabel={Number of hours worked},
                symbolic x coords={$n=50$, $n=100$, $n=150$, $n=200$},  
                xtick=data,  
                ymax=15,
                ymin=0,
                %nodes near coords,  
                %nodes near coords align={above}
                ]  
                \addplot[fill=orange] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 8) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$,15)}; %Solucao 1
                \addplot[fill=red] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 1) ($n=100$, 7) ($n=150$,7) ($n=200$, 12)}; %Solucao 2
                \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 9) ($n=150$,9) ($n=200$, 14)}; %Solucao 3
                \addplot[fill=violet] coordinates 
                {($n=50$,4) ($n=100$, 7) ($n=150$,9) ($n=200$, 13)}; %Solucao 4
               % \legend{Sol.1,Sol.2,Sol.3,Sol.4}  
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}\qquad
\hspace{-2cm}\subfloat[Figura da direita]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \begin{axis} [
                ybar=0pt,
                enlargelimits=0.2,
                width=0.45\textwidth, 
                height=0.35\textwidth,
                minor y tick num = 1,
                ymajorgrids,
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.02,0.5)}},
                bar width = 6pt,
                legend style={at={(-0.2,-0.3)},    
                    anchor=north,legend columns=4},     
                ylabel={Number of hours worked},
                symbolic x coords={$n=50$, $n=100$, $n=150$, $n=200$},  
                xtick=data,  
                ymax=15,
                ymin=0,
                %nodes near coords,  
                %nodes near coords align={above}
                ]  
                \addplot[fill=orange] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 3) ($n=100$, 4) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$, 11)}; %Solucao 1
                \addplot[fill=red] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 2) ($n=100$, 4) ($n=150$,4) ($n=200$, 4)}; %Solucao 2
                \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates 
                {($n=50$, 4) ($n=100$, 12) ($n=150$,12) ($n=200$, 14)}; %Solucao 3
                \addplot[fill=violet] coordinates 
                {($n=50$,3) ($n=100$, 5) ($n=150$,10) ($n=200$,11)}; %Solucao 4
                \legend{Sol.1,Sol.2,Sol.3,Sol.4}  
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Número máximo de frentes de colheita}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```