# Creating a Common Legend for Subfigures with subcaption Package in LaTeX

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, legend

I'm working on a LaTeX template, the elsarticle class from Elsivier, where I have two subfigures created using the subcaption package. I came across [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633360/235441) which provides a solution for having a common legend for subfigures, but it uses the subfigure package. Unfortunately, I've already utilized the subcaption package for previous figures in my draft.

When I attempt to integrate the provided code into my document, I encounter errors like the ones shown in this image.
[image]

I suspect these errors may stem from conflicts between the subfigure and subcaption packages.

**My main question** is: How can I modify the code to have a single common legend for both subfigures while using the subcaption package?

Here's the code snippet generating the figures:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,number]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

%% Title, authors and addresses
\title{2 subfigures with 1 common legend}



\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}



\begin{keyword}
% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword


\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%% main text

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    width=\columnwidth,
    ymin=90,
    ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    symbolic x coords={VGG,GoogLeNet,DenseNet,ResNet},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={ 
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1,
    },
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot [blue, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.22) (DenseNet, 94.85) (ResNet, 93.98)};
\addplot [green, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.81) (GoogLeNet, 95.3) (DenseNet, 94.45) (ResNet, 93.97)};
\addplot [red, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.09) (DenseNet, 94.53) (ResNet, 94.17)};
\legend{Cosine, Euclide, VBD}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{CIFAR-10.}
\label{subfig:cifar10}
\end{subfigure}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    width=\columnwidth,
    ymin=90,
    ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    symbolic x coords={VGG,GoogLeNet,DenseNet,ResNet},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={ 
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1,
    },
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot [blue, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.22) (DenseNet, 94.85) (ResNet, 93.98)};
\addplot [green, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.81) (GoogLeNet, 95.3) (DenseNet, 94.45) (ResNet, 93.97)};
\addplot [red, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.09) (DenseNet, 94.53) (ResNet, 94.17)};
\legend{Cosine, Euclide, VBD}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{CIFAR-100.}
\label{subfig:cifar100}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Ablation study on distance metrics.}
\label{fig:criteria_comparison}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It generates this figure:
[image]

Here's [a link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qkjtpysrmhzh#68ef29) for reproduction.

I'd like the legend to be at the bottom of the figure, between two subfigures. Here's my expected output using Paint:
[image]

I appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: If you could do that: where would you like to place the common legend?

Comment: `\label` statements *must* come after `\caption` statements.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and which packages need to be loaded to make your code compilable. Thanks.

Comment: Your main question, "How can I modify the code to have a single common legend for both subfigures while using the subcaption package?", is unclear. For sure, your code already contains an overall caption that applies to both `subfigure` environments. Are you maybe asking how to get rid of subfigure captions, viz. `CIFAR-10.` and `CIFAR-100.`? Is something stopping you from deleting the associate `\caption` directives?

Comment: Hi @Mico, I've modified the question as per your suggestion. Please consider reviewing it. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way `hyperref` package should be loaded last, with few exceptions. It is not impossible that the reported errors  comme from this wrong ordering, as hyopref can't correctly patch nor  `\capion` nor `\subcaption`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question doesn't look as a real `subfigure` question,  but a `tikz/pgfplots` question.

**New answer**
According to `pgfplots` manual:

**4.9.7 Legends Outside Of an Axis**

you can use the:

`legend to name={<name>}`

option in the first `axis` and no legend in the second one.
This option doesn't draw the legend but store its code.

This code is then executed when you use `\ref{<name>}`. This command can be used even outside of any `tikzpicture`, usually just before the main `figure`'s `\caption`.

Use `\centering` command at the beginning of `figure` environmemt to get it centered, as well as the `subfigure`s.

**Old answer:**

If you don't absolutly need to `\ref`er separately `CIFAR-10` and `CIFAR-100` (using e.g.`\ref{fig:criteria_comparison}-left` or `-right`), here is a possible workaround :

1. Suppress the `sufigure`s and the `subcaption`s.
2. Merge the two `tikzpicture`s into a single one, containing two `axis` environments.
3. Put the second`axis` in a `scope` with the suitable `xshift=...` option
4. Modify the anchor of the `legend (at=...) in the first` axis` and suppress it in the second one.
5. *Optionally*, add the suppressed subcaptions as TikZ `node`s in the corresponding `axis` or `scope`.

Comment: The second answer of @Jhor works with me. Thank you very much!
Note that when putting `\centering` command at the beginning of `figure`, one should remove `\qquad` so that the subfigures stay in 1 row.

Comment: I fear that the line break between the two `subfigure`s doesn't come from the `\centering` but from another thing, most probably too wide tikz pictures, or white line between them. Anyway, it is recommanded to use `\hfill` or `\hfil` instead of `\quad` or `\qquad` to separate the two parts. And put a `%` at the end of lines containong only spacing commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, suggested by @Jhor, just post in in case someone need the code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    width=\columnwidth,
    ymin=90,
    ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    symbolic x coords={VGG,GoogLeNet,DenseNet,ResNet},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={ 
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1,
    },
    legend to name={mylegend},
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot [blue, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.22) (DenseNet, 94.85) (ResNet, 93.98)};
\addplot [green, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.81) (GoogLeNet, 95.3) (DenseNet, 94.45) (ResNet, 93.97)};
\addplot [red, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.09) (DenseNet, 94.53) (ResNet, 94.17)};
\legend{Cosine, Euclide, VBD}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{CIFAR-10.}
\label{subfig:cifar10}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    width=\columnwidth,
    ymin=90,
    ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    symbolic x coords={VGG,GoogLeNet,DenseNet,ResNet},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={ 
        at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=-1,
    },
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
]
\addplot [blue, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.22) (DenseNet, 94.85) (ResNet, 93.98)};
\addplot [green, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.81) (GoogLeNet, 95.3) (DenseNet, 94.45) (ResNet, 93.97)};
\addplot [red, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(VGG, 93.86) (GoogLeNet, 95.09) (DenseNet, 94.53) (ResNet, 94.17)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{CIFAR-100.}
\label{subfig:cifar100}
\end{subfigure}
\ref{mylegend}
\caption{Ablation study on distance metrics.}
\label{fig:criteria_comparison}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I think you're missing an `\hfill` directive immediately after the first `\end{subfigure}` directive. Also, the `\centering` instruction after `\begin{figure}[ht!]` isn't needed.

Comment: @Mico I've added the `\hfill` to the answer. I also tested, without `\centering`, the common legend will be left-aligned.